Django Template - Issues accessing child models / running conditional tests
I am trying to run a conditioanl test in a Django Template based on a count of child objects.
I have passed a varible to the Template called "productcodes" and I can successfully iterate through the each item within it.
Models
class Productcode(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_code


class Test(models.Model):
    worksorder = models.ForeignKey(Worksorder, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    productcode = models.ForeignKey(Productcode, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tester = models.ForeignKey(Tester, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.date

{% if productcodes %}
    {% for code in productcodes %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="show_productcode/{{ code.id }}"> {{ code }} </a></th>
        {% if code.test_set.all.count < 1 %}
          <td> 0 </td>
        {% elif %}
          <td>{{ code.test_set.all.count }}</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>Future Dev WO</td>
      </tr>

    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}

The issue I am having is this if statement is failing with the error:
Unexpected end of expression in if tag.
{% if code.test_set.all.count < 1 %}
I've tested the expression on the shell ok, am I missing something obvious?
Best Regards
Colin.
I am expecting a count of child objects to br printed in the table.

Can you please share the full traceback?

While not the issue, I would advice not to count the number of items through the related name: this will produce an N+1 problem where for N elements, you will make N+1 queries: one to fetch the Productcodes and then one per Productcode to obtain the related Tests.
We can boost this by annotating this in the view, so:
from django.db.models import Count
from django.shorcuts import render


def some_view(request):
    productcodes = Productcode.objects.annotate(ntests=Count('test'))
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'productcodes': productcodes})
Then we can work with:
{% for code in productcodes %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><a href="show_productcode/{{ code.id }}"> {{ code }} </a></th>
    {% if code.ntests < 1 %}
      <td> 0 </td>
    {% elif %}
      <td>{{ code.ntests }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    <td>Future Dev WO</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
You can also work with:
{% for code in productcodes %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><a href="show_productcode/{{ code.id }}"> {{ code }} </a></th>
    {% if not code.ntests %}
      <td> 0 </td>
    {% elif %}
      <td>{{ code.ntests }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    <td>Future Dev WO</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
It is probably also better to use {% url … %} [Django-doc] to generate a path based on the name of a view together with the parameters.

Thank you very much, this has helped a great deal.
